# Qt error: `qApp' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

As I know qApp is global pointer so it should be accessible anywhere but I am getting this error  `error: qApp was not declared in this scope`.

```
  1 #include "textEdit.h"
  2
  3 TextEdit::TextEdit() {
  4 }
  5
  6 void TextEdit::insertFromMimeData (const QMimeData * source) {
  7     if (qApp->mouseButtons() == Qt::MidButton) {
  8         return;
  9     }
 10     QTextEdit::insertFromMimeData(source);
 11 }
 12
 13
```

Comment: `#include<QApplication>` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#qApp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use

```
#include <QApplication>
```

to use the qApp macro. See documentation at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to include header with the declaration.

```
 #include <QApplication>
```

Answer (score 3):

`qApp` is declared in `qapplication.h` file. Include it.